# Remove existing list item in python 3 Telegram bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

I am new in python, I created telegram bot with python 3.
to show product from db I write code like that ,

```
  cart: Dict[List[db.Product, int]] = {}

    for product in products:

        if product.price is None:
            continue

        message = product.send_as_message(self.chat.id)

        cart[message['result']['message_id']] = [product, 0]
        inline_keyboard = telegram.InlineKeyboardMarkup([[telegram.InlineKeyboardButton(strings.menu_add_to_cart,
                                                                                        callback_data="cart_add")]])
        if product.image is None:
            self.bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=self.chat.id,
                                       message_id=message['result']['message_id'],
                                       text=product.text(),
                                       reply_markup=inline_keyboard)
        else:
            self.bot.edit_message_caption(chat_id=self.chat.id,
                                          message_id=message['result']['message_id'],
                                          caption=product.text(),
                                          reply_markup=inline_keyboard)
```

problem is when I want remove this product , I can't remove image of product , I used cart.clear() but it doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution how to remove item from dict "del my_dict['key'] ". I my case  I deleted message which show my product

```
self.bot.delete_message(chat_id=self.chat.id,
                               message_id=temp_msg,
                                    caption=' ',
                                    reply_markup=None)
```